# touchstart and touchend events refering to the same element, while events done on different elements

Tags: javascript, android, dom-events

I am having a problem with my Javascript code for Android tablets.

Suppose I have grid made of several **div** tags. with class "box";

Now I bind event handlers for all these divs in the grid.

When the **touchstart** (mousedown) event occurs and I move the cursor to some other div in the grid (without releasing the cursor) and then release the cursor (touchend) on this current div. When I tried to alert the **id** of this current div (i.e. touchend div), the alert shows the id of the div where the "**touchstart**" has occurred.

```
$(".box").bind('touchstart',function () {alert($(this).attr("id"))});
$(".box").bind('touchend',function () {alert($(this).attr("id"))});
```

Actually this is my first program for the Android tablet. So I need help for this.

Comment: I second that question. To simplify - can touchstart and touchend, of the same touch, occur at different elements? It seems that they cant, so how to simulate it?

Answer (score 2):

This is expected and it would be be very confusing if it did anything else. If the element it ended up on did not have a registered listener you would never get the touchEnd event at all.

You can see where the touch went by looking at the coordinate properties of the touches and you can track it in progress with touchmove.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really get your question. Are you trying to get the alert to display the div id of where you mousedown? You will need to store the id in the touchstart event in a variable and display the value when touchend has occured.

Comment: I am trying to get the id of the div where touchend event occurred.